# How to allow an empty string for a runtime parameter?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm just starting to work with runtime parameters in Azure Pipelines and there's something I can't quite figure out. Considering this Azure Pipelines YAML:

```
parameters:
- name: deployEnvironment
  displayName: Select your target environment.
  type: string
  default: Build_only
  values:
  - Build_only
  - TST
  - PP
  - P
- name: releaseName
  type: string
  default: ''

steps:
- task: ....
```

Why is releaseName a required parameter? I was hoping that by specifying `default: ''` it would be optional to be left empty. The documentation doesn't mention if parameters can be made optional.

[image]

Following up on Kryzstof's answer, I experimented a little further and it seems that a string consisting only of whitespaces is interpreted as empty:

It seems that this single whitespace is interpreted as empty (I've also tried multiple whitespaces).

```
parameters:
- name: myString
  type: string
  default: ' '

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      $MS = $ENV:MS
      Write-Host "myString value is '$MS'"
      Write-Host "Its length is $($MS.Length)"
      Write-Host "is it null or empty? $([System.String]::IsNullOrEmpty($MS))"
      Write-Host "Is it null or whitespace? $([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($MS))"
  env:
    MS: ${{ parameters.myString }}
```

This yields:

> myString value is '' 
>   Its length is 0
>   is it null or empty? True 
>   Is it null or whitespace? True

Comment: There is a pending feature request for this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/optional-runtime-parameter/975396

Comment: The pending feature request has got a few hundred votes now, so I'm guessing it's nearly at the point where Microsoft delete the feature request </s>

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is really strange. But if you put a space `' '` instead of an empty string `''`, then you will be able to trigger pipeline, even deleting that space from field.

[image: build with runtime parameters]

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! Do you know where I would file a bug report for Azure Pipelines? I'll accept your answer, as it provides a decent workaround.

Comment: Seems this workaround no longer works - spaces no longer count as text in this field. @WalterVos have you found another solution since this?

Comment: It actually works, if in the pipeline YAML the default is set to `' '`, but when it is set to `''`, it is not possible to set a single space as parameter value when triggering the pipeline.

Answer (score 14):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters), "parameters cannot be optional".

Putting a space `' '` as the default value will work (as [Krzysztof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2347999/krzysztof-madej) suggested), but the space will remain in the field. If you delete the space in the field so that there is no text value, the default value of `' '` will be used when the pipeline is run.

Answer (score 5):

Single whitespace of runtime parameter is not interpreted as empty. In the example demonstrated by author, the run time parameter is firstly passed to an environment variable `MS`. This step can trim leading and trailing whitespaces. That's why `MS` is an empty string. If try this:

```
parameters:
- name: myString
  type: string
  default: ' '

steps:
- script: |
    echo ">>${{ parameters.myString }}<<"
```

it will produce:

```
>> <<
```

Anyway, passing runtime parameter to script through environment variable is a good workaround trimming whitespace. Otherwise, we have to deal with the whitespace issue in script.

Comment: This is a silly workaround... but it does work. I'll allow it! haha `condition: not(eq('${{ parameters.ZIPPITY_DO_DAH }}', ' '))`